# Netlify 404 error on form submission using Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

Not sure why I cannot submit the form to Netlify. It's goes to the thank you page but it errors out on the `fetch`. Does the forward slash on the `fetch` need to be the path of the current page the form is on? Also not sure if it matters but my file type is .tsx

```
   /** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from "theme-ui"
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import addToMailchimp from 'gatsby-plugin-mailchimp'
import { Parallax } from "react-spring/renderprops-addons.cjs"
import Divider from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/elements/divider"
import Inner from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/elements/inner"
import Content from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/elements/content"
import SVG from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/components/svg"
import { UpDown, UpDownWide } from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/styles/animations"
import Layout from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/components/layout"

import React, { useState, useEffect }  from "react"
import { window, exists } from "browser-monads"
import { navigate } from 'gatsby-link'

const Input = styled.input` 
    background: #242b3c;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px;
    color:white;
`


const SubmitButton = styled.input`
    border: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #3caf7b;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 800;
`    

function encode(data) {
  return Object.keys(data)
    .map((key) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
    .join('&')
}

const promo_games = () =>{

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({})

    const handleChange = (e) => {
      setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const form = e.target
      fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: encode({
          'form-name': form.getAttribute('name'),
          ...state,
        }),
      })
        .then(() => navigate(form.getAttribute('action')))
        .catch((error) => alert(error))
    }


  const {pages, contentOffset, contentFactor}  = useWindowWidth(); 


        return (
       <Layout>

        <Parallax pages={pages} >

    
      <Divider  speed={-0.2}
      offset={0.1}
      factor={1}  bg="linear-gradient(to right, SlateBlue 0%, Indigo 100%)"
      sx={{ clipPath: `polygon(0 15%, 100% 25%, 100% 85%, 0 75%)` }}/>

      <Divider speed={0.2} offset={0.4} factor={1}>
      <UpDown>
        <SVG icon="triangle" hiddenMobile width={48} stroke color="icon_orange" left="10%" top="20%" />
        <SVG icon="hexa" width={48} stroke color="icon_red" left="60%" top="70%" />
        <SVG icon="box" width={6} color="icon_darker" left="60%" top="15%" />
      </UpDown>
      <UpDownWide>
        <SVG icon="arrowUp" hiddenMobile width={16} color="icon_blue" left="80%" top="10%" />
        <SVG icon="triangle" width={12} stroke color="icon_brightest" left="90%" top="50%" />
        <SVG icon="circle" width={16} color="icon_darker" left="70%" top="90%" />
        <SVG icon="triangle" width={16} stroke color="icon_darkest" left="30%" top="65%" />
        <SVG icon="cross" width={16} stroke color="icon_pink" left="28%" top="15%" />
        <SVG icon="circle" width={6} color="icon_darkest" left="75%" top="10%" />
        <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="45%" top="10%" />
      </UpDownWide>
      <SVG icon="circle" hiddenMobile width={24} color="icon_darker" left="5%" top="70%" />
      <SVG icon="circle" width={6} color="icon_darkest" left="4%" top="20%" />
      <SVG icon="circle" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="50%" top="60%" />
      <SVG icon="upDown" width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="95%" top="90%" />
      <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={24} color="icon_darker" left="40%" top="80%" />
      <SVG icon="triangle" width={8} stroke color="icon_darker" left="25%" top="5%" />
      <SVG icon="circle" width={64} color="icon_green" left="95%" top="5%" />
      <SVG icon="box" hiddenMobile width={64} color="icon_purple" left="5%" top="90%" />
      <SVG icon="box" width={6} color="icon_darkest" left="10%" top="10%" />
      <SVG icon="box" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="40%" top="30%" />
      <SVG icon="hexa" width={16} stroke color="icon_darker" left="10%" top="50%" />
      <SVG icon="hexa" width={8} stroke color="icon_darker" left="80%" top="70%" />
    </Divider>

      <Content offset={contentOffset} factor={contentFactor}>


      
     <div style={{ color: `white`}}>
          <Inner >
          <h1  sx={{
            color: "heading",
            m: 1,
          }}></h1>

          <h2>Solution</h2>
          </Inner>
         
     

           <div id="ttm-form">
                <h2>Get Game Catalog</h2>
                
                <div>
                    <form name="promoGames" method="post" action="/thanks/" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                      <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="promoGames"/>
                        <Input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="name"
                            name="FNAME"
                            required
                            onChange={handleChange} 
                        />
                        <br/>
                        <Input
                            type="email"
                            placeholder="email"
                            name="EMAIL"
                            required
                            onChange={handleChange}  
                            
                        />
                        <br />
                        <Input 
                            type="tel"
                            placeholder="phone" 
                            name="PHONE" 
                          onChange={handleChange} 
                        />
                        <br />
                         <Input 
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="company" 
                            name="COMPANY"
                          onChange={handleChange}  
                        />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <b>Follow up with you?</b>
                        <ul style={{listStyleType:`none`}}>
                            <li>
                                <Input
                                    required
                                    type="radio"
                                    value="Yes"
                                    name="FOLLOWUP"
                                    onChange={handleChange} 
                                />
                                <label>Yes</label>
                                </li>

                               <li>
                                <Input
                                    required
                                    type="radio"
                                    value="No"
                                    name="FOLLOWUP"
                                    onChange={handleChange} 
                                /> 
                                <label>No</label>
                                </li>
                        </ul>                                                    
                        <SubmitButton type="submit" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

          {/*  <button style={{color:`white`,background:`linear-gradient(to right, SlateBlue 0%, Indigo 100%)`}}>Go Back </button>*/}


    </div>
    </Content>
    </Parallax>
    </Layout>
        )
   

}

function useWindowWidth() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  // default mobile
  let breakpoints = {
    pages: 2.4, 
    contentOffset: 0.6, 
    contentFactor: 1, 
    width: width
  };

  if(exists(window)){
    useEffect(() => {

      const handleResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);
      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
      };
    });
  
    switch (true) {
      case (width >= 768):
        breakpoints.pages = 1.5;
  
        breakpoints.contentOffset = 0.2; 
        breakpoints.contentFactor = 0.8; 
        break;
    }
  }
  
 

  return breakpoints;
}

    
export default promo_games
```

Comment: I ended up using Getform instead but still wondering why Netlify can't do the same thing. Seems it's a common issue too.